# creating record with standard format of mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Is this standard format of database ?

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"4";}
```

i selected 1,2,3,4

what is name of this format ?
and how can i convert this type of data to standard format like 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a serialized PHP array :). You can [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) it in PHP.